# how to structure data that will be fed into dropdown boxes?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have denormalized data:

```
+----+----------+------+--------+
| pk |   name   | type | animal |
+----+----------+------+--------+
|  1 | alex     | car  | cat    |
|  2 | alex     | bike | cat    |
|  3 | liza     | car  | dog    |
|  4 | danielle | bike | dog    |
|  5 | danielle | bus  | dog    |
+----+----------+------+--------+
```

I would like to have 3 dropdown boxes.

1. `name`
2. `type`
3. `animal`

after the user chooses the option for the first, there should be a cascade effect for the other dropdowns.

**example:** if the user chooses `danielle` for the `name`, the only two options for `type` would be `bike` and `bus` and the only option for `animal` would be `dog`

**How should I structure the SQL tables? Should I denormalize?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that your solution depends on how much data do you have in this table.
If this table is relatively small, you could load it into memory, fill comboboxes by distinct values and then filter data by chosen field.

If it large, you maybe should denormalize your table as @astander says, fill comboboxes with data from reference tables and then when value changes, select filters from SQL like:

```
declare @name_id int -- input parameter, fill it with id of chosen name

-- filter for type combo
select distinct type_id from main_table where name_id = @name_id

-- filter for animal combo
select distinct animal_id from main_table where name_id = @name_id
```